# Ambiguous functions c++ template inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I try to write some generic code which meant for multiple inheritance.
Here is summary of the code:

```
struct Type {};

template <class T>
class OOPPolymorphic {
    friend T;
    void RegisterInheritence(const Type* base) {}
public:
    static const Type* GetType() {
        return thisType;
    }
    virtual const Type* MyType() = 0;
};

class Base :public OOPPolymorphic<Base> {
public:
    virtual const Type* MyType() {
        return OOPPolymorphic<Base>::GetType();
    }
};

class Derived : public Base, public OOPPolymorphic<Derived> {
public:
    Derived() {
    OOPPolymorphic<Derived>::RegisterInheritence(Base::GetType());
    }
    virtual const Type* MyType() {
        return OOPPolymorphic<Derived>::GetType();
    }
};
```

The class Base compiles with no errors, but in class Derived I get ambiguity error:

```
'OOPPolymorphic' is ambiguous '
Candidates are:
 OOPPolymorphic(const OOPPolymorphic<Base> &)
 OOPPolymorphic()
 OOPPolymorphic(const OOPPolymorphic<Derived> &)
 OOPPolymorphic()
```

I really don't understand why it happens. I read that I can write "using ..." in Derived to fix it, but I must assume there isn't because it is homework (I don't know what's the use of the template).
Someone got any idea why it is ambiguity?
Thanks!

Comment: [Can't reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4c509ba40a9991c3).

Comment: This isn't the solution, but `Derived` is inheriting from `Base` which is inheriting from `OOPPolymorphic`, and you inherit `OOPPolymorphic` again, is this possible?